# glTexSubImage2D upload nv12 format very very slow in windows7

Tags: opengl

**Problem:**

I am now working hard to use opengl to render 4K(4096 * 2048)、30FPS video。
I found `glTexSubImage2D` works very very slow in windows7,it need 120ms
to draw one frame.
But it works well in Windows 10,only take 16ms to draw one frame.

Who can tell me why?Below is my source code.

**Source:**

```
void Draw()
{
  glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
  glClearDepth(1.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
  glUseProgram(g_program);

  //Y planner
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texture[0]);
  DWORD startCount = GetTickCount();//Get start count
  if (flag)
  {
      glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, picture->data[0]);
  }
  else
  {
      glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight,GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, picture->data[0]);
  }
  glUniform1i(y, 0);

  //UV planner
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texture[1]);
  if (flag)
  {
      glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RG, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_RG, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, picture->data[1]);
  }
  else
  {
      glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, GL_RG, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, picture->data[1]);
  }
  DWORD endCount = GetTickCount();//Get end count
  printf("upload take time is:%s\n", endCount - startCount);//display upload time
  flag = false;
  glUniform1i(uv, 1);

  DrawHorizontal();

  glBindVertexArray(0);
  glUseProgram(0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Comment: Do you have both OSs installed on the same PC?

Comment: No,The OSs installed on the different PCs.

Comment: Then why do you expect the same performance?  Even if the hardware specs are the same you can get different timing due to different workloads of the machines. Sorry,too many unknowns in your question.